# Получение битрейта каждого кадра

Tags: видео

Ищу возможность получить данные из видеофайла в виде размера/битрейта каждого кадра, не декодированного кадра, а сжатого.

Если на варианты ответа влияет используемый кодек, то рассматривается кодек AV1.

Пример искомой информации:

```
кадр 1 = 450 кб - I-кадр
кадр 2 = 0.3 кб
кадр 3 = 0.4 кб
```

...

Comment: Так Вам битрейт или размер кадра? "Битрейт кадра" звучит странно

Comment: `ffprobe -report -show_frames /path/to/video` в таком виде вам пойдёт?

Comment: @DiD Да, это то что нужно. Тогда прошу вас дать ваш комментарий как ответ, я его отмечу.